# How replication works in Spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark

In hadoop we can control the `replication` factor of data in `cluster of nodes` using configuration files.

But how it can be done in Spark if source is not HDFS...?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Spark is a cluster computation engine, it does not replicates data or stored data implicitly. Spark processing is based on rdd, if due to node failure any of the data partition is lost it can be recalculated using DAG.

Though while persisting data you can store the data in memory or disk. For example StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_2 means the rdd partitions will be replicated twice while saving it in memory.

Comment: so you mean to say, if we want we can control the replication while proessing using StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_2 etc options, but if node fails it will not re-process RDDs if StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY_2 is enabled, it will take data from there and process, but if its not enable then all re-processing will be done again .Correct ..?

Comment: Yes, you use storage levels while persisting the data using persist api. In this case the partition will be stored in two nodes. In case of failure of one node data will be taken from other node so it will save recalculation of rdd from dag.